# Is there a step by step instruction to enable tracing of kubernetes components?

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I'm running Kubernetes version v1.24.0, trying to enable tracing in Kubernetes components and so I can instrument my custom controller to work with tracing.
However, the instruction https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-traces/#trace-collection is very high level to me. Is there any other detailed instruction on how to enable tracing?

Note: I'm not looking for tracing on applications running in K8s env instead kubernetes components like kube-api-server, controller, kube-manager...

What I've done so far:
I've started k8s-api-server with below two args

```
--feature-gates=APIServerTracing=true
--tracing-config-file=/tmp/tracing.conf
```

once the api-server pod is up and running, should I able to see traces when creating a pod in the api-server pod logs? I just see usual logs, nothing specific to tracing.
what am I missing?

I tried deploying opentelemetry collector as mentioned at `https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/#kubernetes` but

Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: where you able to configure traces for k8s system components?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look in this repository. I have tried to implement and I was able to trace the traces for kubernetes components.

https://github.com/rkdutta/OpenTelemetry

all steps except 08 and 09 are relevant for your query. 08 & 09 are for application level tracing with auto instrumentation. Exact steps to follow are specified in the [ReadMe.md](https://github.com/rkdutta/OpenTelemetry/blob/main/README.md)

Please give a vote to the answer if it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, will check and update. Appreciate your help